# Solving an ODE Numerically with SciPy

Tags: python, matplotlib, scipy, differential-equations

I'm trying to find a numerical solution and eventually graph, the Gyllenberg-Webb model (cancer cell growth model). This model looks like:

[image]

Where `β` is the reproduction rate of proliferating cells, `µp` is the death rate of proliferating cells, `µq` is the death rate of quiescent cells, and `r0` and `ri` are functions (transition rates) of `N(t)`. Also `N(t) = P(t)+Q(t)`.

For my purposes here I defined `r_0(N) = bN` and `r_i(N) = aN` to make things more simple.

My problem is when I try and plot my solution with pyplot I get

> ValueError: x and y must have same first dimension

which I guess is self-explanatory, but I'm not sure how to go about fixing it without breaking everything else.

My code, which I've done only for the first equation so far, is:

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import scipy.integrate

def fun(P,t, params):
    beta, mp,b,N,Q = params
    return(beta-mp-(b*N))*P+(a*N)*Q

params = (0.5,0.6,0.7,0.8,0.9)

tvec = np.arange(0,6,0.1)
s1 = scipy.integrate.odeint(
    fun,
    y0 = 1,
    t = tvec,
    args = (params,))

#print(s1)

plt.plot(fun,tvec)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are currently plotting `fun` vs. `tvec`. What you actually want is to plot `tvec` vs `s1`. You will also have to define the parameter `a` in `fun`; I set it to `1` in the code below:

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import scipy.integrate


def fun(P, t, params):
    beta, mp, b, N, Q = params
    return (beta-mp-(b*N))*P + (1.0 * N)*Q

params = (0.5, 0.6, 0.7, 0.8, 0.9)

tvec = np.arange(0, 6, 0.1)
s1 = scipy.integrate.odeint(
    fun,
    y0=1.,
    t=tvec,
    args=(params,))

plt.plot(tvec, s1)
plt.show()
```

This will plot:

[image]

Answer (score 2):

In the end you will want to solve the coupled system. This is not complicated, just make the state object a vector and return the derivatives in the correct order.

```
def fun(state,t, params):
    P, Q = state
    beta, mp, mq, a, b = params
    N = P+Q
    r0N, riN = b*N, a*N
    return [ (beta-mp-r0N)*P + riN*Q, r0N*P - (riN+mq)*Q ]

params = (0.5,0.6,0.7,0.8,0.9)

tsol = np.arange(0,6,0.1)
sol = odeint( fun, y0 = [ 1, 0],  t = tsol,  args = (params,))

Psol, Qsol = sol.T; plt.plot(tsol, Psol, tsol, Qsol)
```

[image]

Comment: that's actually super helpful, thank you kind stranger